# Real roots of a polynomial function

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove the for every $0 < k <3$ there are at least two real roots of the function $f\left(x\right)=x^5-8x^2+k$.

Comment: Hint: $f(0)=k>0$, $f(1)=1-8+k<0$, and $f(2)=k>0$.  In fact, you can prove that for all $k$'s that you consider, there are *exactly* three real roots using Descartes' rule of signs.

Comment: I actually did this on my paperbook and didn't notice it. I feel dumb. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that

$$f(-\infty)=-\infty, f(0)=k, f(1)=k-7,f(\infty)=\infty.$$

Then by continuity, $f(x)$ reaches any value in $(k-3,k)$ at least three times.

Answer (score 0):

$f'(x)=x(5x^3-16)$ so the function $f$ has extremuns at $x_1=0$ and $x_2=\sqrt[3]{\frac{16}{5}}\approx1,4736$ and this is independant of the constant $k$.

The function $f$ has always a real root because of the odd leading-exponent and it has the three real roots while the maximum is greater than $0$ and the minimun is lower than $0$ (mean value theorem).

This clearly happen when $f(x_1)>0$ and  $f(x_2)<0$ i.e. when $0<k<K$ where $K= 8x_2-(x_2)^5$. When $k=K$ one has $f'(K)=0$ and for other values of $k>K$ the minimun being greater than $0$ there 
 is no more three real roots.

The value of $K$ is approximately 10.4234 thus, a fortiori when $0<k<3$ the asked property is satisfied.

Final Note.- For $0<k<3$ never there are just two real roots (always two positive roots and one negative root)